# Matplotlib: ValueError even when passing vmin/vmax to Norm?

Tags: matplotlib

Matplotlib changed how `vmin` and `vmax` should interact with norms (see API changes: https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.5.0.html#stricter-validation-of-function-parameters). However, I'm getting an error that doesn't make sense. Specifically, I have the following code:

```
    sns.heatmap(avg_sampled_customer_assignments_by_customer,
                ax=ax,
                mask=np.isnan(avg_sampled_customer_assignments_by_customer),
                cmap='Spectral',  # 'jet',
                norm=LogNorm(vmin=cutoff, vmax=1.),
                )
```

Yet my process is killed due to the error: `ValueError: Passing parameters norm and vmin/vmax simultaneously is not supported. Please pass vmin/vmax directly to the norm when creating it.`

I tried removing the keywords, but the error remained. Why am I being told to pass `vmin/vmax` to the norm when I am doing that (at least as far as I can tell)?

Comment: `heatmap` is apparently setting vmin and vmax as well.  Probably should report to seaborn if it has not been already.

Comment: Oh good catch. I'll go open an issue.

Comment: Your github issue says you're using seaborn 0.9.1. I can't reproduce with seaborn 0.11.1 and matplotlib 3.5.1, so maybe your seaborn is too old.

Comment: @tdy that was indeed the problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My seaborn version was too old. The issue is now resolved after updating from 0.9.1 to 0.11.1.